# Quantifying volatility with limited data?

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, exploratory-data-analysis, volatility-forecasting

I have ~400 time series's that I need to quantify volatility over. The only information I have is mean, min, and max values for each time stamp.

Here is a sample series for your convenience:

[image]

My intention isn't for rigorous analysis, but rather for EDA. These series's represent historical market rates for shipping in between pairs of cities, and I want to make a network of nodes (superimposed on a map of the US) with the edges of this network referring to how stable the price is.

**My gut is telling me to just take the standard deviation of all mean values, but this would ignore min and max values. Am I right to ignore min and max? Do they not offer anything worthwhile without other information?**

Answer (score 0):

Quantify volatility ? I don't know what you mean by that.

But if you want to model the variance of your times series, go for ARCH(GARCH) modeling.

You will find plenty of ressources about it with R.

https://www.math.umd.edu/~bnk/Ked_Symp_Friday.pdf here's a simple course I think that help to be introduced to it.

Comment: thank you! What I was looking for was a way to assign a number value to how stable or unstable my time series' were over the past twelve months. I have a novice understanding of statistics and will look into ARCH modeling via your link.